# Disable submit button upon revisiting the form page

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, button

Is there a way a form page can detect that after you answer the form and submits, and then **REVISITS** the form page, the submit button is now **DISABLED**?

**Important Note:** If a different user, the form can be answered and submitted, if the SAME user visits again the link, the submit button is DISABLED.

Is this possible using HTML, CSS and JavaScript?

```
<form>
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="First Name"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Last Name"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to achieve this functionality strictly client side, you can store whether the user has submitted the form in [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

For example, you can add a `submit` event listener to the form that sets the submitted state to true in `localStorage`. On page load, retrieve that state, check whether it is true, and if so, whenever the user submits the form, prevent form submission.

For example:

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form')
var isDisabled = !!localStorage.getItem('submitted');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    if(isDisabled){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("You have already submitted")
  }
    localStorage.setItem('submitted', true);
})
```

JsFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Spectric/dowc1qea/

Keep in mind, however, that since `localStorage` is modifiable by the client, they can always set the state to false programmatically and submit the form again.